# JavaScript'ный CSS создает проблему в PHP

Tags: jquery, javascript, php, css

[image]

Как сделать чтобы и запись "A,Google" была так же в синем квадрате, как и "B, Yahoo!"?

Дело в том, что я задаю вот такой код в PHP:

```
<body>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
printf("
    <table cellspacing='10'>
        <tr>
           <td>%s</td>
           <td>%s</td>
        </tr>
    </table><br />", $row['title'], $row['link']);
}
?>
</body>
```

А CSS код для TD находится в jS файле:

```
$('td').css({
'height' : grid_height,
'width' : grid_width,
'background-color' : '#69F'
});

$('table').css({
'position' : 'absolute',
'left' : '20px',
'top' : 0,
'bottom' : 0,
'right' : 0,
'margin-top' : margin_top
});
```

Comment: Ссылку на рабочий пример можете привести?  html весь сразу генерится, или что-то докачивается ajax'ом?

Comment: Это скрытая реклама от google и yahoo! :]

Comment: @sergiks AJAX'а нет. Обычная ХТМЛ страница, которая заполняется из БД и CSS которого динамический и находится вместо STYLE.CSS в SONGS.JS. Хочу чтобы все записи из БД были внутри той синей плитки с пробелами на 1 <br />

Comment: Приведите весь HTML, который получается в странице. В какой-нибудь pastebin его засуньте, и ссылку сюда.

Comment: У вас позиционирование всех таблиц абсолютное — они помещаются одна над другой, видна только последняя.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sWh2D/ <--- Вот. Выложил все. HTML и jQuery @sergiks

Comment: @navi1893 не php, а html, который получился в результате. Исходный код страницы, Cmd+U в FireFox.

Comment: CSS не может создавать проблему PHP — они работают по разные стороны баррикад, пора бы уже усвоить. Ну и можно по F12 смотреть, что происходит. Вопросу — минус.

Comment: Мне вот интересно - почему в вопросе один код, а по ссылке - другой? Так задумано?

И для тех, кто не знает - если есть куча элементов с одним и тем же ID, то $("#ID") вернет не все, а только [первый](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) элемент, иначе зачем тогда этот ID нужен?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
<body>
    <table cellspacing='10'>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>", $row['title'], $row['link']);
}
?>
    </table>
</body>
```

И, кстати, у вас всегда генерируется одна и та же айдишка — <td id='td1'>%s, %s</td>.

Comment: Опять не то. Выложил скрин в вопросе(Обновил). Смотрите что получилось

Comment: все! Остальное сам доделал. А в чем проблема была?

Comment: Прооблема в том, что вы вообще не знаете самых основ ХТМЛ, ЦСС, Яваскрипта и делаете всё наобум, а если не получается, то задаете здесь кучи дилетантских вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Измените позиционирование с `absolute` на `relative`, будет [как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/Mg2kh/).

Comment: изменилось только местоположение. "A, Google" теперь внизу, но опять же НЕ в синей плитке :(